# Create a distribution list with multiple users

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I want to create distribution groups in Office 365 from a CSV file.

In my CSV file there's a column that contains multiple users, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Here's my PowerShell code :

```html
$Groups = Import-Csv -path "C:\Users\Youssef IBRAHIMI\Desktop\Script create LD Azure\groupsMM2.csv"
$Groups |
ForEach-Object {
$Name = $_.Name
$DisplayName = $_.Name
$Alias = $_.Aliases
$PrimarySmtpAddress =$_.Email
$ManagedBy = $_.Owners 
$Members = $_.Members
$Notes = $_.Description
$isArchived =$_.isArchived
If($isArchived -eq $True ){
#Write-Host "The  :$Members " 
New-DistributionGroup -Name $Name -DisplayName $DisplayName -PrimarySmtpAddress $PrimarySmtpAddress -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Members $Members -Notes $Notes
 }
 }
```

When I execute the script, I get the following error about members:

```
Je suis trop paresseux pour traduire ce message d'erreur en anglais.
```

(A.k.a.: `L'objet "thach.vo maxime.bauche stephan.coquelet" est introuvable. Assurez-vous que vous l'avez correctement tapé ou spécifiez un autre objet.`)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that all members are being passed as one big long string, if the users in your CSV are separated by a space you can use the `-split` operator in PowerShell to separate them into individual names:

```
$Members = $_.Members -split " "
```

Which you can easily add to your script like so:

```
$Groups = Import-Csv -path "C:\Users\Youssef IBRAHIMI\Desktop\Script create LD Azure\groupsMM2.csv"
$Groups |
ForEach-Object {
    $Name = $_.Name
    $DisplayName = $_.Name
    $Alias = $_.Aliases
    $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.Email
    $ManagedBy = $_.Owners
    $Members = $_.Members -split " "
    $Notes = $_.Description
    $isArchived = $_.isArchived
    If ($isArchived -eq $True)
    {
        #Write-Host "The  :$Members " 
        New-DistributionGroup -Name $Name -DisplayName $DisplayName -PrimarySmtpAddress $PrimarySmtpAddress -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Members $Members -Notes $Notes
    }
}
```

This should pass `$Members` as a string array instead of one big long string.

Answer (score 1):

I had another problem for the column members : each member was written in a separate line.

So in addition to `-split` I use `Replace("`r`n",' ')`
here's my code:

```html
$ManagedBy = $_.Owners    
$ManagedBy1 = $ManagedBy.Replace("`r`n",' ') 
$ManagedBy2 = $ManagedBy1 -split " "
```